# Audio recording not Working after Factory Reset?

Tags: windows-10, audio

Ok, so because of some reasons I did a factory reset on my PC.
Now I noticed that I can't chat in Discord, TeamSpeak or Skype anymore because apparently there is no Audio input from my side.
I tried plugging in my Headphones and the problem still persisted.

Before the Factory reset I could peak both without and with the headphones normally.
Funny thing is also, that my headphones aren't even listed as a connected audio device even though I can hear through them.
Another thing I'm missing is that when earlier I plugged my earphones in a popup appeared asking me as what kind of audio device I'd like to use the headphones. This is now also missing.

Anyone know what happened or how to fix that?

Comment: Have you checked your `Device Manager` to make sure no drivers are missing?

Answer (score -1):

Probably this is a driver related issue. Even if in the Device Manger all drivers are OK, maybe the generic Windows driver for your audio device can cause problems. In my experience, the best way is to always install the driver provided by the manufacturer of the hardware. Many times, especially with older devices, older versions of the driver made for an older OS version work better and have all the original functionalities even on win 10.

Simply download the driver from the manufacturer's site and install it. It should override the standard windows driver and fix your issue. If it doesn't work (supposing you have an old hardware), try to uninstall and delete the generic win driver from the device manager and, before installing the older downloaded driver, make it run with compatibility settings for the original driver OS version.